# Python 'click' CLI framework and overriding global default options

Tags: python, click, command-line-interface, overriding

I've inherited a python CLI application that uses click as a framework.
The writer used _ _ init _ _.py in a particular directory to mandate a parameter
(note required = true):

```
COMMON_OPTIONS = {
    'owner': option(
        '--owner',
        type=Choice(sorted(platform_conf['allowed_owners'])),
        default=None,
        required=True,
        expose_value=True,
        help='Set the resource owner.',
        callback=cb_owner)
}
```

However I need to add a command to a file underneath that _ _ init _ _ which does not
need that option (notice we specify only 'profile' but the init file also mandates owner. Profile is declared in this python file, in the directory under the init file):

```
@account.command('provision-thingy')
@options(['profile'])
def provision_thingy(profile):
   pass
```

Does anyone know how I can tell Click to let me ignore the mandatory 'owner' option for this function only?